# Converting a string in SQL Server 2012 and Postrgesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

How can I convert the following, the last 8 digits after the hyphen are the date. The last 2 digits of the year near need to be at the beginning with the letters removed

```
AB000260-21032022
CR110223-20032022
```

to

```
22-000260
22-110223
```

Ideally in both SQL Server 2012 and PostgreSQL

Comment: Given "AB000260-21032022", you want to pull the last two characters and concatenate that to the substring starting at position 3 for 6 characters in length. Does that give you some rather suggestive hints (as far as SQL Server is concerned)?

Comment: 2 digits years? Really shouldn't be doing that more than 20 years after Y2K either!

Comment: "Hiding" a date in a combined value like that is a really bad design (it violates 1st normal form). The first part and the second part should be two different columns where the date should be stored in a column defined as `date`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is bad design for database, but accounting people in companies like to use such constructs for document (invoices etc) numbers. This usually creates two problems for us - how to build those numbers based on some human-understandable rules and later - how to parse those numbers in some other systems :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sample script uses standard SQL and runs equally well in mode Postgres and SQL server on dbFiddle.
NB: It relies on the input string having the same format and number of characters every time.
See 2 links below

> ```
> CREATE TABLE samples( sample varchar(25));
> insert into samples values
> ('AB000260-21032022'),
> ('CR110223-20032022');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   CONCAT(
>     SUBSTRING(sample, 16, 2),
>     '-',
>     SUBSTRING(sample, 3, 6) 
>   ) formatted_string
> FROM samples
> ```
>
> ```
> | formatted_string |
> | :--------------- |
> | 22-000260        |
> | 22-110223        |
> ```

*db<>fiddle Postgres [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=126607275d6eb923dbb613a33ef183a7)*

*db<>fiddle SQL server [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=338f1e3443604f6e9a5caaf0774face6)*

Comment: Just a little nitpicking: `SUBSTRING(sample, 16, 2)` is not "standard SQL" although many DBMS support it. And neither is the `concat()` function. But whether it's standard SQL or not, does not matter at all here.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for your remark. do you know of a document or website which defines "standard SQL" "AINSI SQL" or a similar idea? In the absence of such a reference I work on what the majority of databases accept.

Comment: Unfortunately the ANSI SQL standard is not available for free. Some websites publish older versions (e.g. [here](https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/), but it's quite cumbersome to read anyway.

Comment: For the record this script works in MariaDB, MySQL, Postgres and SQL server.
It doesn't work in Oracle or SQLite